# Dimensions of finite-dimensional vector space and its dual

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensioanl vectors spaces. Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $T'\in\mathcal{L}(W',V')$ where $T'$ denote the dual map of $T$ as defined in Axler (2015).

> $\textbf{My Question}$: Are the dimensions of $W$ and $W'$ the same? If so or not so, what is the basic intuition behind this?

Reference:
Axler, Sheldon J. $\textit{Linear Algebra Done Right}$, New York: Springer, 2015.

Comment: Yes. For finite dimensional spaces, the dimensions of a space and its dual space coincide.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense --- $T$ is a linear map, and linear maps don't have dimensions.

Comment: You may awant to read about the *dual basis*. This may give a nice mathematical intuition in these matters.

Comment: @JohnHughes I fixed it. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that, the set of all linear transformations from a $n$-dimensional vector space $\textsf V$ to a $m$-dimensional vector space $\textsf W$ is isomorphic to the set of matrices $\textsf{M}_{m\times n}(F)$, which has dimension $mn$.
In other words :
$$\dim \mathcal{L}(\textsf{V},\textsf{W}) = \dim (\textsf V) \dim (\textsf W)$$
Now, as we can always consider the field $F$ as a vector space over itself, of $1$ dimension, it follows that
$$\dim(\textsf{W}^*)=\dim \mathcal{L}(\textsf{W}, F) = \dim (\textsf W) \dim (F) = \dim (\textsf W)$$